# how to get name of the function called in the class through its constructor

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
public class ApplicationClass
{
    public  ApplicationClass() 
    {
        // Some code here                   

        public bool Check() 
        {
            // some code here

        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the `Check`  function in a click event

```
protected void CheckFunction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new ApplicationClass().Check();
}
```

Now in the `ApplicationClass` constructor I want to get the info about the name of the function which is called and parameters if any i.e the `Check` function.

How can I get these details ?

I want to save all the functions that are being called. Instead of placing the call to function at every function can I have it at one place?
It need not be inside a constructor necessarily.

Comment: Why do you want to know? It's a bad design.

Comment: How would you expect that to work? During the constructor the class is being created therefore it doesn't know about you calling `Check` at that point.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  I want to save all the functions that are being called. Instead of placing the call to function at every function can I have it at one place?

Comment: @James is there any other way to get it? I dont want to have the code to save function name inside each and every function

Comment: What do you plan to do with the function name?

Comment: I am trying to mine the data about the usage of the application and understand about user behavior by getting these function names which will imply the usage

Comment: @vignesh without knowing what you plan to do with the name then I can't really suggest anything.

Comment: @James I want to use it for getting to know the most and least used functionalities in the application.

Comment: @vignesh yeah, I get that but you still haven't explained what you intend on doing with the information i.e. is it going to be inserted into a DB, logged to a file etc.

Comment: Your intentions - data mining for analysing user behavior - rather seem to be something which should be logged to a file. I do not understand why you actually need the information you are looking for; you could read the methods calls out of a detailed logfile though (if you create one).

Comment: @James No i am planning to create a webservice which will store all the function names into the DB. So when i consume the webservice i should call the method only  once which will keep track of all function calls and save them

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Maybe it looks like it is because of the notation. This is what your code expands to:

```
protected void CheckFunction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var temp = new ApplicationClass();
    temp.Check();
}
```

If you just want to call a method of class without needing an instance, you might want to use a static method - at least your example looks like it. Of course initialization must be done elsewhere or in a static constructor. A static constructor is invoked only once though!

```
public static bool Check() 
{
    // some code here
}

ApplicationClass.Check();
```

If you want information about the methods invoking the current method you may use.

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
```

Please note that fetching the stack trace can be considered slow, it should not be used in a loop or performance critical code.

Comment: Not possible. You can't get the information of `Check` in the constructor since it isn't called then yet.

Comment: Right, I did not interpret the description correctly. Hmm .. will update answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. If it was the other way around, you could have used the `StackTrace` class to check what was called, but as said, that is not the case now. (If you had called `Check` first, it would have appeared on the stack then)

You could opt to use `Expression` or [`LamdbaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) class to retrieve information of the call.

See the question and answers from [Get the name of a method using an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225302/get-the-name-of-a-method-using-an-expression) to get an idea how Expressions might be handy.

Comment: @vignesh: Need more help?