# Pass method as param via expression

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, expression, invoke

I need to have the ability to pass a method of my class (or base-class) to be passed to a base-class method (as it will have to do some more stuff there).

I known about the following posibility: In my base-class I have the method `public void Call(Action action)` which will simply call `action()` and do other stuff.

But I wan't some more restrictive as by now I can put everything in this method, e.g. `Call(() => string.Format("Some {0}, "text));` But I only want to allow methods of own type or base-type.

I think about something like `public void Call(Expression<Func<MyClassType, Action>> expressionToAction)` but I don't get the right point here.

Is this even possible? With the expression-param I get the error that the method must return `Action` which is totally not what I want.

Comment: How about a simple virtual method in base class, overridden by a concrete implementation in the subtype?

Comment: `Func<X, Action>` doesn't guarantee anything about the returned `Action`. What are you trying to achieve actually? If you provide a concrete example of why you would want to do this, perhaps there is a better way to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve "only methods of this class" at compile time. There is no restriction that would let you do that on generic an non-generic types.

If run-time check is enough - pass an expression (use `Action` not `Func` - `Expression<Action<T>`) and inspect body of the expression similar to [Get the name of a method using an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225302/get-the-name-of-a-method-using-an-expression).